# Is re-creating an art from someone else's art copyright violation and can be sued?

Tags: copyright

Let's say I want to create a flame like this one and use it in my app:

[image]

But, I'm not good enough to make it from scratch and make it look beautiful as in the link. So, instead, I copy the flame image from the link, paste into my graphic software and then use curve function to create the curves over the image in the link and create a flame vector art in this way for myself. Is this way of using someone else's work as template to create my own icon violation of copyright?

Even though, the final product looks the same, but it is not exactly the same, since I "created" it getting help from someone else's work. So, can I be sued for that?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a legal question, not a usability question. There are absolutely legal ramifications in your actions, or similar actions. It would be inappropriate to provide legal advice that may not be accurate for your situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not so sure that the violation issue is as clear cut as the other answers. If you take an image, use a part of that image as, effectively, a template for your own icon image creation, which you represent in a way different from the original, I'm not sure it can be considered a copyright violation.

Some of it depends on how distinctive the original image is... if you were to do that with a very recognizable type of image, even if simple or iconic - say a Keith Haring figure - the lineage would be clear enough that yes, you could get in trouble.

But icons rarely have any sort of real attribution these days: they are created and populate interfaces, and one designer uses another as inspiration, and before you know it there are thousands of them, most indistinguishable from the next. Can you tell me which of the icons from this Google search represents a Facebook thumbs up, as opposed to another one? Would it matter if you used any one of these as a starting point for your own? Who's to say you didn't just silo a photo of your own hand and use that as your starting point?

[image]

Your flame icon, likewise, is something that has been created and re-created so many times and is so simple and iconic - and publicly available - that there is very little to indicate that one person or another created it. You could even simply change the curves a bit, stretch it out, use it in a different treatment, and it would be all but impossible to say that you'd copied it from anywhere. Take a look at icon sets in Dribbble some time and tell me how much significant variety you see around a single icon type.

[image]

Finally, and importantly, **when it comes to icons you WANT your icon to be recognizable, simple, not too different from others**, in the interest of universal recognition; you want to be able to **leverage the same mental models** that have been so successfully used in the past for certain associations. If you create something too far afield from the other icons out there - without some very serious work and consideration - it may no longer be interpreted with the meaning you intend.

I believe that it is fine to use existing icons as a starting point to create your own, as long as you manipulate and treat them in some way that makes them at least marginally unique to your particular treatment and layout.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 1):

Unless the image has a license that allows re-use and modification such as 
[Attribution-ShareAlike 2.0 Generic (CC BY-SA 2.0)](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/), then yes, it's a copyright violation and yo can be sued.

It will be way easier to pay someone and have artwork created from scratch to avoid any kind of issues, something like this could be done really cheap.

Anyways, try to find if the image you want falls into the Creative Commons realm, and if so, under which license. Take a look to [**Understand the license Section**](https://wiki.creativecommons.org/wiki/Considerations_for_licensors_and_licensees#Considerations_for_licensees) in order to understand the rights and limitations of the licenses

Answer (score 1):

## “So, instead, I copy the flame image from the link”

You said it right there: *copy*. I'm not a lawyer, but I think we can all agree that your actions are unethical. Isn't that why you're asking in the first place? It seems wrong to rip off another persons skill so you assume there must be some legal ramification. And there *could* be.

If you aren't skilled at a particular thing (eg building a house, flying a plane, designing an icon, etc), then you contract someone who is. That's how this whole economy thing works.

In this case, you may be able to contact the original designer and pay a small fee. They already did the work, so it's very likely they'll be happy to get paid for it again.

You can also just find a suitable replacement for free or nearly free on a site like [IconFinder.com](https://www.iconfinder.com/search/?q=fire).